# Which ResourceDictionary is better

Tags: c#, uwp

What are the differences between resx and xaml dictionaries when developing a UWP platform for UNO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one type of **ResourceDictionary** and its extension is **Xaml**, **Resx** is a **resource** file format that is mostly used in **WPF** and is used to store resources like (image, string,...) The same file is known in **UWp/Uno** is Resw format. But a resourcedictionary is used to define styles and controls